# Adding up the total amount of each array child item by key in Laravel, Blade or PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add up the total amount of each `receiptitems->value` per receipt/parent.

The ideal outcome is to loop through the receipts and display;

```
receipt->id 
receipt->merchant
receipt->totalValue
```

The total value of each of the child values (i.e. the whole receipt value).

Example JSON output:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "user_id":1,
      "image":"58a31ba406d16.jpg",
      "merchant":"Tesco",
      "created_at":"2016-04-23 22:02:58",
      "receiptitems":[  
         {  
            "receipt_id":1,
            "category_id":2,
            "value":5285
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":1,
            "category_id":5,
            "value":5231
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":1,
            "category_id":5,
            "value":6822
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "user_id":1,
      "image":"58a31ba4073c8.jpg",
      "merchant":"Tesco",
      "created_at":"2016-09-19 02:55:38",
      "receiptitems":[  
         {  
            "receipt_id":2,
            "category_id":2,
            "value":7009
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":2,
            "category_id":7,
            "value":2147
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "user_id":1,
      "image":"58a31ba407a26.jpg",
      "merchant":"Tesco",
      "created_at":"2016-08-06 12:30:27",
      "receiptitems":[  
         {  
            "receipt_id":3,
            "category_id":7,
            "value":4598
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":3,
            "category_id":2,
            "value":8799
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":3,
            "category_id":3,
            "value":773
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "user_id":1,
      "image":"58a31ba407e69.jpg",
      "merchant":"Tesco",
      "created_at":"2016-12-10 21:21:43",
      "receiptitems":[  
         {  
            "receipt_id":4,
            "category_id":5,
            "value":883
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":4,
            "category_id":5,
            "value":3013
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":4,
            "category_id":2,
            "value":1013
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":4,
            "category_id":1,
            "value":3243
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":5,
      "user_id":1,
      "image":"58a31ba408187.jpg",
      "merchant":"Tesco",
      "created_at":"2017-01-18 14:12:16",
      "receiptitems":[  
         {  
            "receipt_id":5,
            "category_id":7,
            "value":1355
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":5,
            "category_id":1,
            "value":1547
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":5,
            "category_id":1,
            "value":1640
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":5,
            "category_id":1,
            "value":2466
         },
         {  
            "receipt_id":5,
            "category_id":8,
            "value":2689
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I've been trying in the controller as well as in blade templates and I can't get the result I need. I've been looking at array_sum() http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php but I'm not sure how to implement it.

I've tried in the RecriptsController:

```
$receipts = Receipt::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->with('receiptitems')
    ->get();

foreach ($receipts as $receipt) {
    $result = array_sum($receipt->receiptitems->value);
};

return $result;
```

And also in Blade template:

```
@foreach($receipts as $receipt)
    <li>{{ $receipt->merchant }}</li>
    <ul>
    @foreach($receipt->receiptitems as $item)
        <li>{{ array_sum($item->value) }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you want [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in combination with [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php):

```
foreach ($receipts as $receipt) {
    $total = array_sum(array_column($receipt['receiptitems'], 'value'));
    print_r($total);
}
```

`array_column` pulls out the `value` keys from the `receiptitems` sub-array. Then `array_sum` totals those up. But you have an collection of objects, so you actually need a slightly different approach based on [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
foreach ($receipts as $receipt) {
    $total = array_sum(array_map(function ($o) { return $o->value; }, $receipt->receiptitems));
    print_r($total);
}
```

As an aside, you may want to consider a `Receipt::getTotalAttribute()` mutator, which would return the total of the items and to simplify how to you interact with the model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting a `array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given` error

Comment: Sounds like a collection. Perhaps you want to cast it to an array with `(array)` or use `->toArray()` or equivalent cast method.

Comment: I've added `return $total->toArray();` outside of the loop and I still get the same error (referring to the second line within your example).

Answer (score 0):

Although the questions is answered and I got the result I wanted. A friend helped me with another option (Collections) which also worked:

```
public function index()
{
    $receipts = Receipt::where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->with('receiptitems')
        ->get();

    $collection = collect($receipts);
    $data = $collection->map(
        function($receipt) {
            $r = new stdClass;
            $r->id = $receipt->id;
            $r->merchant = $receipt->merchant;
            $r->amount = collect($receipt->receiptitems)->pluck('value')->sum();
            $r->date = $receipt->date;
            return $r;
        }
    );

    return view('transactions', compact('data'));
}
```

Hope it helps someone else.